# Javascript custom sorting issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

So i have this function:

```
function sortJSFiles( files) {
var src = [];
var vendor = [];

files.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.indexOf('src/') > -1) {
        src.push(item);
    } else {
        vendor.push(item);
    }
});

src.sort(function (a, b) {
    function replaceCB(r, a, i) { return r.replace(a, i); }

    var replace = ['noctis.js', 'noctis.ctrl.js', '.module.js', '.ctrl.js'];

    return replace.reduce(replaceCB, a).localeCompare(replace.reduce(replaceCB, b));
});

return vendor.concat(src);}
```

Which basically sort js files in my specific order but the problem is that there are involded js in directories too and those are load firstly which i dont, for example:

```
Running "index:build" (index) task[
'vendor/angular/angular.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-material/angular-material.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js', 
'vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js', 
'vendor/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js', 
'templates-common.js', 
'templates-app.js', 
'src/app/noctis.js', 
'src/app/noctis.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/account.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/characters.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/detail/detail.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/admin.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/users.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/donate/donate.js', 
'src/app/account/donate/donate.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/settings/settings.js', 
'src/app/account/settings/settings.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/account/vote/vote.js', 
'src/app/account/vote/vote.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/membership/membership.module.js', 
'src/app/news/news.js', 
'src/app/news/news.ctrl.js', 
'src/app/widgets/playersOnline/playersOnline.js', 
'src/app/widgets/rankings/rankings.js', 
'src/app/widgets/serverDetails/serverDetails.js', 
'src/common/directives/feeds/feeds.js', 
'src/common/directives/panel/panel.js']
```

You see in directory membership, normally it should be loaded firstly membership.js and than the js from the subdirectories. Anyone can moddify my function to achieve what i want? Thanks.

Comment: "*normally it should be loaded firstly membership.js and than the js from the subdirectories*" - why would you expect that? **d**ialogs < **m**embership. If you somehow want to treat your items specially as paths, you will have to do so explicitly and not use standard string comparison.

Comment: Meaning that it should be like membership.module.js to load first before the dialogs js

Comment: Also like the rest of others, for ex you are in folder X and this has a main JS and there are also in subdirectories others js too and no matter of that order of the alphabet that js in root folder should always load first. You understand?

Answer (score 0):

Not alphabetic, but at least now the files in the subdirectories are loaded later.

```js
var dependencies = ["src/common/directives/panel/panel.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/characters/detail/detail.js", "src/app/account/account.js", "src/app/noctis.js", "vendor/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/characters/characters.js", "vendor/angular/angular.min.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/panels/users.ctrl.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.js", "templates-common.js", "src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js", "src/common/directives/feeds/feeds.js", "vendor/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js", "src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js", "src/app/widgets/rankings/rankings.js", "src/app/widgets/playersOnline/playersOnline.js", "src/app/news/news.js", "src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js", "src/app/account/donate/donate.js", "src/app/news/news.ctrl.js", "src/app/account/settings/settings.ctrl.js", "src/app/account/donate/donate.ctrl.js", "src/app/membership/membership.module.js", "src/app/account/settings/settings.js", "src/app/account/vote/vote.js", "vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js", "vendor/angular-material/angular-material.min.js", "vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js", "src/app/noctis.ctrl.js", "vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js", "vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.ctrl.js", "templates-app.js", "src/app/account/dashboard/panels/admin.ctrl.js", "src/app/widgets/serverDetails/serverDetails.js", "src/app/account/vote/vote.ctrl.js"]

var src = dependencies.filter(function isVendor(dep) {
  return dep.startsWith("src/");
});

src.sort(function(a, b) {
  var depth = a.split("/").length - b.split("/").length;
  var postFixNr = a.split(".") - b.split(".");
  return depth === 0 ?
    postFixNr === 0 ?
    a.localeCompare(b) : postFixNr : depth;
});

console.log(src);
```